# Cannot change chart.js color fill or y axes

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am trying to make a real time graph using `chart.js`, but I cannot seem to change the color fills.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var canvas = document.getElementById('updating-chart'),
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
  startingData = {
    labels: ["A", "B", "C", "D"],
    datasets: [
    {
      label: "Product A",
      fillColor: "rgba(206, 70, 90, 1)",
      strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
      pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
      pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
      data: [65, 59, 80, 81],
      options: {
        scales: {
                  yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true,
                    min: 0,
                    max: 10
                    }
                  }]
                }
              }
    }
    ]
  };

  var myLiveChart = new Chart(ctx,{
    type: 'bar',
    data: startingData,
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: true
  });

  setInterval(function(){
    // Get a random index point
    var indexToUpdate = Math.round(Math.random() * startingData.labels.length);

    // Update one of the points in the second dataset
    myLiveChart.data.datasets[0].data[indexToUpdate] = Math.random() * 100;

    myLiveChart.update();
  }, 500);

</script>
```

I've clearly changed the axes and set the y to a maximum, but it still overflows and keeps dynamically changing the axes length. How do I fix this?

Also the color still seems to be grey for the first bar, even though I changed the `rgba` values. Help?

Answer (score 0):

refer the below link for changing the colors.try background-color.If you share the fiddle it will help.

### http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#chart-configuration-colors

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in your datasets array. Color will change.

```
backgroundColor:"rgba(206, 70, 90, 1)"
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Smita31Jain/4zpuxvke/

For overflow and dynamically changing axes length issue, take out **options** property object code from **startingData** object's **dataset** array and add it to **myLiveChart** chart instance. Refer below jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/Smita31Jain/zzpkxg3k/

Hope this is what you are looking for.